# How to get whole row data or specific data of a row in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have this grid code below

```
    function Cancel() {        
        var url1 = URL
        $("#List").jqGrid({
            url: url1,
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['RowId', 'Cancel' ,'Date'],
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'rowId', index: 'rowId', hidden: true, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 80, align: 'left' },
{name: 'cbox_cancel', index: 'cbox_cancel', editable: true, formatter: "checkbox", edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, sortable: false, width: 95, align: 'center' },              
                    { name: 'tDate', index: 'Date', editable: false, sortable: false, width: 70, align: 'left' },                  
              ],
            pager: $('#Pager'),
            rowNum: 5
            rowList: [5,10,15],
            pgbuttons: false,           
            sortname: '',
            sortorder: '',
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: '/Content/themes/redmond/images/',
            height: '100%',
            loadComplete: function (result) {
                var ids = jQuery("#List").getDataIDs();
                var len = ids.length, newLine;
                if (len < 5) {
                    AddNewRowToGrid(len, "#List");
                }                          
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

And I have a separate button, I am trying to do is to get the row data (example: I want to get the rowid , if checked box is check and the date.. Same row) after I click my button.

Comment: Your question is not full clear. In any way you should probably use `getGridParam` with `"selrow"` (or `"selarrrow"` if you would use `multiselect: true`) to get the rowid of currently selected row and then use `getRowData` to get the data of selected row identified by rowid. I recommend you to confider to use `multiselect: true` to create the column with checkboxes which can be used to select multiple rows (instead of `cbox_cancel`), to use `jsonReader: { id: "rowId" }` and remove `rowId` column (one need to know the format of data returned from `url: url1` to be sure that one can do this).

Comment: You should always write which version of jqGrid you use (or have to use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Some options which you currently use can be removed (`sortname: '', sortorder: ''`) other options like `imgpath: '/Content/themes/redmond/images/'` not exist at all (`imgpath` was removed starting with 3.5). It's not recommended to use different `index` and `name` values (see `name: 'tDate', index: 'Date'`). One should remove `index`.

Comment: @Oleg I solve it but I don't know if my experiment code will work fine. But now I have another problem it is different from the title. If you don't mind i'll ask it. I have 2 checkboxes now in jqgrid and I have 3 data(1,2,3) and I check the check box in data 1(first checkbox) and data 3(second checkbox) after I close my dialog box which contains my jqgrid all the data 3 check boxes both checked :(

Comment: The problem exist in your **code**. One can solve the problem if you just explain, what the program should do. I still don't understand what your program do. You write about "checkboxes", which the user check, but the code contains no `multiselect: true` and you defined only `cbox_cancel`, which checkboxes can be checked only in the corresponding lines are **in editing editing**. It's unclear from the code, which you posted, how you start editing and how the edited data will be saved. I can't help you if I have no idea what you do.

Comment: @Oleg I will open another topic for my problem.

Comment: Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710360/jqgrid-checkboxes-becomes-check-after-closing-a-dialog-box) of my new problem. Hope you can help.