# JQgrid checkboxes becomes check after closing a dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I'm using this code below for my JQgrid inside a pop-up dialog box.

```
function LeaveHalfDay() {
    var url1 = URL

    $("#LeaveHalfDayDataEntryList").jqGrid({
        url: url1,
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames: ['RowId', 'With Halfday <br /> Morning', 'With Halfday <br /> Afternoon', 'Date', 'Day'],
        colModel: [
                { name: 'rowId', index: 'rowId', hidden: true, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 80, align: 'left' },       
                {name: 'cbox_leave_half', index: 'cbox_leave_half', editable: true, formatter: cboxFormatterLeaveHalfDay, formatoptions: { disabled: false }, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, sortable: false, width: 70, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'cbox_leave_halfPM', index: 'cbox_leave_halfPM', editable: true, formatter: cboxFormatterLeaveHalfDayPM, formatoptions: { disabled: false }, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, sortable: false, width: 70, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'LStartDate', index: 'LStartDate', editable: false, sortable: false, width: 70, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'LDate', index: 'LDate', editable: false, sortable: false, width: 55, align: 'left' }         
          ],
        pager: $('#LeaveHalfDayDataEntryPager'),
        rowNum: 5,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20],
        sortname: '',
        sortorder: '',
        viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: '/Content/themes/redmond/images/',
        height: '100%',           
        loadComplete: function (result, rowid) {
            var ids = jQuery("#LeaveHalfDayDataEntryList").getDataIDs();
            var len = ids.length, newLine;
            if (len < 5) {
                AddNewRowToGrid(len, "#LeaveHalfDayDataEntryList");
            }
            $("#LeaveHalfDayDataEntryPager").css("width", "auto");
            $("#LeaveHalfDayDataEntryPager .ui-paging-info").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

I have this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KkWM.jpg) as for example after closing my jqgrid inside my dialog box. At my scenario I only check the morning checkbox in dated `8/2/2016` and afternoon checkbox in dated `8/4/2016`. And I try to reopen it all 4 check boxes are check. If ever this problem will solve my another problem also will be solve because they link to each other.

And for my controller for my jqgrid here is my code

```
DateTime _startDate, _endDate, _startCntDate;
        TimeSpan difference;
        _startDate = StartDate;//DateTime.Parse(StartDate);
        _endDate = EndDate;//DateTime.Parse(EndDate);
        _startCntDate = StartDate;//DateTime.Parse(StartDate);
        difference = _endDate - _startDate;
        int i, objCnt = 0;


        for (i = 0; i < (difference.Days + 1); i++)
        {
            if (!(_startCntDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || _startCntDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
            {
                objCnt++;
            }
            _startCntDate = _startCntDate.AddDays(1);
        }
        var rowsObj = new object[objCnt];
        int rowId = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < (difference.Days + 1); i++)
        {
            if (!(_startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || _startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
            {
                rowsObj[rowId] = new { id = rowId, cell = new object[] { rowId, false, false, _startDate.ToShortDateString(), _startDate.DayOfWeek.ToString() } };
                rowId++;
            }
            _startDate = _startDate.AddDays(1);
        }
        var a = rowsObj.Skip((page - 1) * rows).Take(rows);
        var result = new JsonResult();
        result.Data = new
        {
            totalRecords = rowId,
            total = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)rowsObj.Count() / (float)rows),
            page = page,
            records = a.Count(),
            rows = a
        };
        return result;
```

Comment: When you ask questions with a wall of code, they rarely get answered promptly. Maybe try stating the question and what you tried first. Then show the least amount of code possible to show what you tired. In the meantime, I will try my best to answer this for ya :)

Comment: Its not really clear what you are asking. Maybe update the question and I will take another look

Comment: @joncodo So far i'm trying my best to solve it. I'm trying any code that comes to my mind and even experimenting codes.

Comment: @joncodo I stated my scenario there. Below the grid code

Comment: Can you maybe further explain this line: "And I try to reopen it all 4 check boxes are check." That is the part that I am confused about

Comment: @joncodo as mention above after I close my dialog box and reopen it the morning and afternoon check boxes are check in dated 8/2/2016 and 8/4/2016 even I only check the morning in 8/2/2016 and afternoon in 8/4/2016

Comment: @joncodo thanks for the concern and time. I got it now. Thanks

Comment: no problem. Sorry I could not be of more help here. Maybe you can post your answer that you found here somewhere. I would be curious to see the error. :)

Comment: @joncodo because of my formatter.